# How to receive messages with sandboxed iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an html page with a iframe that is sandboxed, so it can't access parent DOM. But is there a way I can still send serialized data from the iframe to the parent with event listeners and from the parent to the iframe too?

Comment: I guess `postMessage` should work even with a sandboxed iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use post messages either from an iframe to its parent, or from a parent to its iframe.

`postMessage` should work fine, even from within a sandboxed `iframe`.